# An error occurred, please solve run package manager

Tags: server, 23.04, microsoft

I run
Sudo apt-get -f install

I got
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-beta.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: Comment out with # or correct line 1. Or remove that file from sources.list.d.